# stackoverflow error on updatechildren() firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, stack-overflow

Im getting a strange problem when updating the firebase database at an existing node.
it comes back with InvocationTargetException and further below a stackoverflow error(is that where the site gets its name from).
Ive tried everything i could think of and searched SO and still cant fix it. The problem doesnt seem to be in the build file. I recently changed my app package name and added it to the firebase console.
Ive also just noticed that the log debug section is still refering to my apps previous package name com.example.shopper. could this be causing it.
Or is it the two lines pointed out below.

```
 else {
        InventoryItem updatedItem = items.get(position).getInventoryItem();
        updatedItem.setPrice(price);
        updatedItem.setQuantity(quantity);
        updatedItem.setUnitName(unitType);
        Map<String, Object> databaseUpdate = new HashMap<>();
        databaseUpdate.put(updatedItem.getName(), updatedItem);
        Log.d(TAG, "done: updatedItem: "+updatedItem.toString());
        inventoryDatabaseReference=inventoryDatabaseReference.child(updatedItem.getCategory());
        Log.d(TAG, "done: updateNotWorking:  "+inventoryDatabaseReference.toString());
        inventoryDatabaseReference.updateChildren(databaseUpdate).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: "+e.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Its the line with the failure listener that the trace points me to. I added the listener to see what was going wrong but found as soon as the line is called i get the error as in the log above is the final successful operation
To get the values to change the item by I use a dialog fragment. This fragment is used for multiple similar purposes such as the initial placement of that data and works for that purpose.
The trace below it points to the first line calling donelistener.done

```
   builder.setTitle(title).setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (setPrice || isUpdating)
                doneListener.done(quantity, unitSelected, position, priceSet);
            else {
                priceInBasket = priceSet * quantityToBuy;
                Log.d("n", "onClick: TotalPrice toBasket " + priceInBasket + "individiual price" + priceSet);
                doneListener.done(quantityToBuy, buyerItemUnitName, position, priceInBasket);
            }
        }
    })
```

Sorry if this is a simple error and a waste of time but Ive spent all last night on this and can not see the solution. 
Anything else you may need just let me know
The trace is as below

```
06-07 14:13:21.434 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper     D/CurrentInventory: done: updatedItem: InventoryItem{quantity=6, price=0.5, unitName='/100g'}
06-07 14:13:21.435 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper D/CurrentInventory: done: updateNotWorking:  https://shopper-a34fb.firebaseio.com/ShopInventory/-KkgxqStvYBMm1fz0lOZ/Energy%20Drinks
06-07 14:13:21.764 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper I/dalvikvm: threadid=1: stack overflow on call to Ljava/lang/AbstractStringBuilder;.enlargeBuffer:VI
06-07 14:13:21.764 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper I/dalvikvm:   method requires 28+20+20=68 bytes, fp is 0x419a2334 (52 left)
06-07 14:13:21.764 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper I/dalvikvm:   expanding stack end (0x419a2300 to 0x419a2000)
06-07 14:13:21.764 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper I/dalvikvm: Shrank stack (to 0x419a2300, curFrame is 0x419a248c)
06-07 14:13:21.765 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-07 14:13:21.765 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper D/dalvikvm: threadid=1: detach (group=0x41aa3ce0)
06-07 14:13:21.765 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41aa3ce0)
06-07 14:13:21.765 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
06-07 14:13:21.765 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-07 14:13:21.772 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
```

a bunch of these

```
06-07 14:13:21.859 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5052K (46469), 38% free 8607K/13700K, paused 34ms, total 35ms
06-07 14:13:21.860 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
06-07 14:13:21.860 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
06-07 14:13:21.860 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
06-07 14:13:21.860 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
```

It then shows the lines where my code is above is

```
06-07 14:13:21.877 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
06-07 14:13:21.877 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
06-07 14:13:21.877 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
06-07 14:13:21.877 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaF(Unknown Source)
06-07 14:13:21.877 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(Unknown Source)
06-07 14:13:21.877 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.updateChildren(Unknown Source)
06-07 14:13:21.878 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at com.aihsoftware.shopper.CurrentInventoryFragment.done(CurrentInventoryFragment.java:288)
06-07 14:13:21.878 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at com.aihsoftware.shopper.DialogFragments.AddItemToInventoryDialogFragment$2.onClick(AddItemToInventoryDialogFragment.java:145)
06-07 14:13:21.878 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
06-07 14:13:21.878 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
06-07 14:13:21.878 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
06-07 14:13:21.878 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     rr:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-07 14:13:21.894 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:    ... 557 more
06-07 14:13:21.895 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
06-07 14:13:21.906 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:163)
06-07 14:13:21.906 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:311)
06-07 14:13:21.906 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at android.net.Uri.encode(Uri.java:1864)
06-07 14:13:21.906 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at android.net.Uri$PathPart.getEncoded(Uri.java:2112)
06-07 14:13:21.906 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri.appendSspTo(Uri.java:1216)
06-07 14:13:21.906 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri.makeSchemeSpecificPart(Uri.java:1205)
06-07 14:13:21.906 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri.getSsp(Uri.java:1188)
06-07 14:13:21.906 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:     at android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri.getSchemeSpecificPart(Uri.java:1197)
06-07 14:13:21.906 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/System.err:    ... 559 more
06-07 14:13:21.906 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
```

finally a bunch of this in red

```
06-07 14:13:21.927 14585-14585/com.example.testing.shopper E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.testing.shopper, PID: 14585
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance everybody

EDIT: done some more digging and the invocation target is a wrapper around the stackoverflow error. forgot about pointing that out.
This means that there is a problem with URI's and the stringbuilder. does firebase database .updateChildren() not work with URI's

Comment: Your InventoryItem is probably not an allowed value to Firebase. You can only put String, Long, Double, Boolean, Map<String, Object> and List<Object> into Firebase values (see: firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)
Tip: You can use auto-value-firebase to easily convert you Java pojo:s to Firebase value

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around. Im happy it works but not that I still dont know why the stackoverflow error is occurring.
I changed the updateChildren() to point to each individual data member of the object instead of the object itself. This worked but first there was an error which when updating an item more than once led to another tree.
For example i have
category:{
item:{
price:1
quantity:1
}
}
and it would result in
category:{
 category:{
price:2(updated)
quantity:2(updated)
}
 item:{
price:1
quantity:1
}
}
This keeps repeating for as many updates as required and I believe that is where the issue came from. However I cannot understand what the error in my code is. I always use updateChildren() as best practice.
All i can think is these lines are the problem causing multiple subcategories.I placed category in both of these as variations

```
databaseUpdate.put(updatedItem.getName(), updatedItem);
    inventoryDatabaseReference=inventoryDatabaseReference.child(updatedItem.getCategory());
```

This is what worked

```
databaseUpdate.put(updatedItem.getCategory()+"/"+updatedItem.getName()+"/price",price);
        databaseUpdate.put(updatedItem.getCategory()+"/"+updatedItem.getName()+"/quantity",quantity);
        databaseUpdate.put(updatedItem.getCategory()+"/"+updatedItem.getName()+"/unitName",unitType);
inventoryDatabaseReference.updateChildren(databaseUpdate)
```

Comment: Check my comment above